# Why am I getting a large white space below all HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

For some reason on this page using a mega drop down there is a giant white space below the all the content enabling you to scroll past the footer. Can you please help me figure out what is going on?

I'm quite certain it has to do with the mega drop down because when you hover over it the white space disappears. (menu item 'coop and career' is mega)

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/student-success/

Strangely, these two pages also use it and don't have the issue (some other styles are messed up on these two, but that doesn't affect it as I had them on the same theme/styles as the broken page and they still didn't have it - they're on broken styles currently so another dev can look into something else)

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/athletics/ (fitness center menu item)

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/sdvadev/ (programs menu item)

Thanks.

EDIT: also when you inspect the element the white space gets proportionally larger compared to the size of the inspector toolbar - if that helps.

Comment: What browser are you having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to set`#menu-item-197 {overflow:hidden}`

or simply `#pagenav li {overflow:hidden}`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the relative positioning. For instance, a div block naturally structered at the bottom is forcefully placed at the top. In this case, the space of the div block will always be preserved thus leaving behind white spaces!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because in **custom.css** you had:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

remove **min-height: 100%**, and it works well.

P.S.
I'll change footer to be without absolute positioning, because it makes horizontal bar to appear under the browser window, like this:

```
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```